# Use of יצ"ו, expanded to יבנה ציון וירושלים (May He build Zion and Jerusalem), how and where used?

Tags: hebrew, acronyms, yerushalayim-jerusalem

I'm trying to remember where I have seen this (יצ"ו) used.  I think it appears sometimes in sefarim, sometimes after the names of towns (not in Israel), and that the intent is to hope for the rebuilding of the Beth Hamikdash.

Would this ever have appeared on a matzeva as well?  And I don't mean when it is used after a living person's name, with the other expansion of ישמריהו צורו.

Examples would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Madeleine

Comment: You sure it's יבנה "may He build" and not יבנו "may they be built"? I ask only because the passive seems much more common in similar phrases. ([Cf.](/q/11271/170))

Comment: Actually, I don't know, because every time I try to look for an expansion of this rashe tevot in a dictionary, I get the other more traditional expansion.  But here's an example from the start of a sefer, that has the rashe tevot after the names of the towns:

Comment: רב...  בבארא פארק, מלפנים  אב"ד דעברעצין ונייהייזל יצ"ו

Comment: The particular example you give in your last comment can be referring to the person.

Comment: If referring to a person, I think it would have had the other expansion of              
 ישמריהו צורו וגואלו but with the expansion I asked, I have seen it too often after a place/town.  It makes me wonder if in explaining how they became known in certain places, it would have been better if they could have been in Jerusalem.  Besides, if it were for a person, it would probably have been better closer to his actual name, rather than after a long list of where he had lived.  But that's just in my humble opinion.